# Trigger to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR but execute inner commands

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, triggers

I'm working on the following PL/SQL `trigger`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_1
BEFORE UPDATE ON worker
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.type = 'PRESIDENT' THEN
    INSERT INTO trigger_log VALUES (sysdate, 'Nope.', 'No change.');
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20111, 'Can not change!');
  END IF;
END;
```

Here, I want to cancel the `UPDATE` command on the `worker` table, when a `PRESIDENT`'s `payment` is about to get changed. At the same time, I wish to log this command into table called `trigger_log`. The problem is, when I `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` the UPDATE got cancelled, but the logging (`INSERT INTO trigger_log`) aswell. How can I `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` or throw an `EXCEPTION`, but still have all commands to be run inside the `TRIGGER`?

Comment: Just for try, put a `commit;`  after the insert command (and i'm not really sure you should do this). I'm saying that you should not do this because you are in a trigger and a commit to every statement will be at least a cost process to the database. I think you should consider to do this log in another way.

Comment: Plus, a commit inside a trigger could mess up with a state of a transaction.

Comment: You *cannot* commit in a trigger except with an autonomous transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to commit your `INSERT`-Statement before raising the error.

Maybe think about [AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonomous-transactions.php)

**EDIT**
As others have stated already, you should not and cannot `commit` inside a trigger (exception autonomous transaction). So think about using the solution of Tom Thomas or calling a logging-procedure/-package.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a `stored procedure` from your trigger. That stored procedure should be declared as `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`. Try like this,

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE 
    PROCEDURE log_error_p
    AS
         PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO trigger_log VALUES (SYSDATE, 'Nope.', 'No change.');
         COMMIT;
    END;
```

--

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_1
    BEFORE UPDATE ON worker
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
         IF :OLD.TYPE = 'PRESIDENT' THEN
              log_error_p();
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20111, 'Can not change!');
         END IF;
    END;
    /
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, never use a commit or a rollback inside the trigger. It's a coding standard. As for your question i think this is a better way than raise_application_error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_1
BEFORE UPDATE ON worker
REFERENCING OLD as o AND NEW as n
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
     InsertException EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
     IF o.TYPE = 'PRESIDENT' THEN
          RAISE InsertException;
     END IF;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN InsertException THEN
     INSERT INTO trigger_log VALUES (SYSDATE, 'Nope.', 'No change.');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Comment: -1 Since your exception handler doesn't re-raise the exception, the original update will be allowed without error.

Comment: So even though its a before update trigger, I need to prevent the insertion manually? Can you please elaborate? I would love to learn what mistake i made...

Comment: Your trigger doesn't raise any exception to the caller, so it will allow the update to proceed. See @Dba's answer for the correct answer to this question.